# Combining Windows Forms and XNA, but lacks "Game" instance

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I am currently working on a Map Editor for my 3D game, but I am having some problems getting the using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game included.

My 3D engine is stored in a library, and the constructor for it needs the Game instance and a GraphicsDevice.
The GraphicsDevice is not a problem since i used some example from App Hub ([link text](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)), but using the "Game" is not included in it. Does anyone know how I would fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: Yep, I have already tried that :)

Comment: It is basically just the code from http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1, but my constructor for my library looks like this: public 3DEngine(Game gameInstance, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the entire point of the WinForms sample is to remove the use of `Game` (and the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` assembly). The Game class does things that you probably do not want to have happen within your editor.

I would recommend modifying your 3D engine so that it does not require an instance of the Game class, in order to be created.

What are you using from Game, anyway? A `ContentManager`, perhaps? Just pass that in directly.

But if you really must reference the Game class, add a reference to the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly to your project. Do this by right clicking the project in the solution explorer, selecting Add Reference and finding it in the list of .NET assemblies. Make sure you get correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I too am writing a 3D engine in XNA, called '[Vanquish](http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc)'

Now that I've seen your constructor, you need to remove the `Game` variable from this.  Create a `public static` variable called `Instance` in your Engine.  Then, in your constructor add the following:

`Instance = this;`

From your WinForm application, whenever you need to use `Game` you can use `engine.Instance`.

Comment: Will this work when I'm going to work with the engine in an XNA game then?

Comment: Yes.  You'll have access to the Game class from the Instance variable.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot :) Looks really great with your engine ;D Good luck on further development!